# Cardinality of tree of height $\kappa$, $\kappa$ measurable

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

The following is Theorem $2.8$ in Chapter 13 of Hrbacek and Jech's "Introduction to Set Theory" ($3^{\text{rd}}$ edition):

> **Theorem $\bf{2.8}$** Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal. If $T$ is a tree of height $\kappa$ such that each node has less than $\kappa$ immediate successors, then $T$ has a branch of length $\kappa$.

The proof begins with:

> *Proof.* $\;$ For each $\alpha \lt \kappa$, let $T_{\alpha}$ be the set of all $s \in T$ of height $\alpha$. Since $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, it follows, by induction on $\alpha$, that $\vert T_{\alpha}\vert \lt \kappa$ for all $\alpha \lt \kappa$.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is true for $T_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. If, for every $x, y \in T_{\alpha}$, $\{z \in T \; \vert \; z \lt x\}$ = $\{z \in T \; \vert \; z \lt y\}$ implies $x = y$, then I've been able to bound the size of $T_{\alpha}$, given that $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible. But how does one bound $\vert T_{\alpha}\vert$ when each set of predecessors can correspond to multiple elements of $T_{\alpha}$?

Comment: Not sure why they didn't just state the theorem "if $T$ is a tree of height $\kappa$ such that each level has size $<\kappa,$ then $T$ has a branch of length $\kappa$," or, more succinctly, "there are no $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees." That's both correct without implicit normality assumptions, and, at a glance, more consonant with the surrounding discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is of course at limit stages. But any point at the limit levels is determined by the branch below it. So we just need to understand how big can a tree of height $\alpha$ be, if all the levels are smaller than $\kappa$.

Since $\kappa$ is regular, we can find an upper bound on the sizes of the levels, say $\lambda$. So, now the tree has size $\alpha\cdot\lambda$. And how many branches can it have? At most $2^{\alpha\cdot\lambda}$, which is less than $\kappa$.

Comment: "[A]ny point at the limit levels is determined by the branch below it." Are you saying that, for limit $\alpha$, '$x, y \in T_{\alpha}$, $\{z \in T \; \vert \; z \lt x\}$ = $\{z \in T \; \vert \; z \lt y\}$ implies $x = y$' must hold?

Comment: Yes. This is implicit in every discussion about trees. If not, simply add $\kappa$ many points on top of $\omega$, and you have a counterexample of height $\omega+1$. Now, I don't have a copy of Hrbacek and Jech's book, so I can't see what exactly they say or don't say about trees in general. But the discussion is always about "normal" trees, where every node splits and every limit level is determined uniquely by its predecessors.

Comment: That was actually precisely my point of confusion. There was no mention (as far as I can tell) of assuming trees to be "normal" in the given section (though I guess, given your counterexample, that should have been evident from the context).

Comment: The thing is that if a tree is not normal, we can normalise it by simply adding a common predecessor between each branch (up to a limit level) and the points that follow it (and collapse any non-splitting intervals). So the assumption should really be that the normalised tree has the property about successors.